# Postgres optimize for insert/read only

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a database with the following characteristics:

- Many inserts (in the range of 1k/second)
- Lots of indices on the data, complex joins
- NO Deletes or updates, only inserts, read and table drops
- I don't care if the reads to the database reflect accurate state
- Data isn't critical, I'm already running fsync=off

I already know a fair bit about postgres optimization, but I was hoping there might be some additional tricks that are more suited to my particular use case.

Comment: This sounds like a job for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ to me.

Comment: Give this a shot: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/01/03/waiting-for-9-1-unlogged-tables/

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong tool for the job. Why use an ACID compliant database when ACID compliance is not what you want? Why not use something designed for speed like http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/ or http://www.hypertable.org/

Comment: Which side of the equation would you like to tune first? the `INSERT`s or `SELECT`s? You've hit the biggies. Unlogged tables are going to be hot, but until then... have you increased your `checkpoint_segments` yet?

Comment: Inserting needs to be optimized. sayap, that is a great post. I'm testing this now in the 9.1beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the WAL, perhaps by pointing it to /dev/null or RAMDISK.  Note there is some speculation that you may not be able to restart the DB after even a clean stop, so I advise caution and testing.

Make sure you cluster your tables.  Partitioning might help as well.

Certainly disable synchronous_commits.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_tune_the_database_engine_for_better_performance.3F

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [unlogged tables](http://rhaas.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/when-your-data-isnt-made-of-gold.html) (available as of 9.1) for that. It's basically a table for which the WAL is disabled.